# Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element' error in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, javascript-objects

I'm trying to make auto expanding (upwards) text-box with JavaScript in a React application. Got this error.  Also tried using window.getElementbyId instead of but that doesn't work.

[image: error image]

```js
<ReactTextareaAutocomplete
  id="textbox"
  className="message-input"
  placeholder="Type your message.."
/>

const tx = document.getElementsByTagName("ReactTextareaAutocomplete");
const maxheight = 100;
const normalheight = window.getComputedStyle(tx[0]).getPropertyValue('height').replace("px", "");
for (let i = 0; i < tx.length; i++) {
  tx[i].setAttribute("style", "margin-top:-3px;" + "height:" + (tx[i].scrollHeight > maxheight ? maxheight : tx[i].scrollHeight) + "px;overflow-y:hidden;");
  tx[i].addEventListener("input", OnInput, false);
}

function OnInput() {
  this.style.marginTop = (normalheight - this.style.height.replace("px", "")) + "px";
  this.style.height = "auto";
  this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight > maxheight ? maxheight : this.scrollHeight) + "px";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement `useRef()` instead to access the element.

Add the `ref` attribute on the element.

```
<ReactTextareaAutocomplete ref={rtaRef} />
```

And for the function:

```
const tx = useRef(null);
```

If you have multiple instances of the component, use the loop to create unique `ref` using the loop index.

Comment: but still the same error is showing

Comment: The "ref" code that I used is a replacement for the "getElementsByTagName". 

While you are coding, you use the tag name "ReactTextareaAutocomplete", but during render, React treats it as a component and converts it to html, so you can't use "getElementsByTagName".